# Prove that there is $c$ such that $\int_a^c f(x)dx = \int_c^b f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be integrable on $[a, b]$. Prove that there is some $c$, such that $\int_a^c f(x)dx = \int_c^b f(x)dx$.

I can rewrite this in terms of integrals $2F(c) = F(a) + F(b)$, but I don`t know how to proceed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $G(c)=\int_a^cf(x)\,\mathrm dx-\int_c^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$. Then $G$ is continuous and $G(a)=-G(b)$.